# UDP Socket Async Receive

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, udp

I deliberately issue socket.BeginReceiveFrom call and pass the buffer of 16 bytes,
despite that I know that the other side send messages of about 2,000 bytes. I do that deliberately because I just want to read the header of 16 bytes first and then issue a second receive call that will read the payload which is of variable length. As you may guess the header includes 4 bytes that indicates the payload length.

That said, I get an exception that says that the buffer is not big enough to receive the message... How come?

Answer (score 2):

Thats not possible, udp are datagrams instead of streaming. You cannot read messages partial.

Comment: I simply recall that I did that once in C++ by setting a flag in socket options...Am I wrong here?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with it. sorry